# write dataframe to cassandra facing BusyPoolException

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to write dataframe to cassandra using these line of code,was able to write to table for someday but suddenly the error came

```
alertdf
.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                 .options(Map("keyspace" -> "dummy", "table" -> "dummytable"))
                  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
                  .save()
```

I get this below error,not able to find out what is getting wrong

```
  ERROR QueryExecutor: Failed to execute: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RichBoundStatement@7dba59e2
        com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: **.**.**.**/**.**.**.**:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [**.**.**.**/**.**.**.**] Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)))
            at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.reportNoMoreHosts(RequestHandler.java:211)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$1000(RequestHandler.java:46)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.findNextHostAndQuery(RequestHandler.java:275)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution$1.onFailure(RequestHandler.java:338)
            at shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1310)
            at shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
            at shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ImmediateFuture.addListener(Futures.java:106)
            at shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1322)
            at shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1258)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.query(RequestHandler.java:297)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.findNextHostAndQuery(RequestHandler.java:272)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.startNewExecution(RequestHandler.java:115)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:95)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeAsync(SessionManager.java:132)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:40)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.executeAsync(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:40)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.executeAsync(Unknown Source)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.QueryExecutor$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.apply(QueryExecutor.scala:11)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.QueryExecutor$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.apply(QueryExecutor.scala:11)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncExecutor.executeAsync(AsyncExecutor.scala:31)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TableWriter.scala:199)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TableWriter.scala:198)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.foreach(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:31)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:198)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:175)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:112)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:145)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.writeInternal(TableWriter.scala:175)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.insert(TableWriter.scala:162)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:149)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that your servers are overloaded, and don't process your requests on time.  I recommend to try to tune [write-related configuration parameters](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#write-tuning-parameters), like, `output.concurrent.writes`, `output.throughput_mb_per_sec` and other, but I would start with first 2.

Comment: thanks for your reply,how should be determine the optimal value of these two factor?

Comment: It’s really hard to say without knowing what hardware you are using, how cassandra is tuned, etc. Start with setting output throughput to 50 and see if it will work. If survives, try to increase, if not - decrease...

Comment: what all should I mention so that I could get some help from you in this

Comment: Sometimes increasing the throughput, etc. is doing more harm... It's really depends on your hardware, etc., plus Spark code itself